# OAuth for third party API on Jupyter?

Tags: python, oauth, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Python on a Jupyter notebook for data analysis, and want access to a third party API ([Mendeley](https://dev.mendeley.com/reference/topics/authorization_overview.html)) that uses OAuth. There used to be a work-around with a server on Heroku that produced a token manually, but that's been discontinued recently.

This must be an insanely common problem, but I can't find a maintained library that supports it. Most Python OAuth libraries are server-only; there's a well-supported JupyterHub-OAuthenticator, but IFAICS that is using OAuth for a different purpose.

[ipyauth](https://pypi.org/project/ipyauth/) looks the business, but it's not been updated much and it's not documented how to extend it for new services. That situation usually means there's something better-supported available.

What is the currently-maintained Jupyter-Python-ThirdPartyAPI library, please?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps or not, but I had to do an Oauth using PKCE Authorization flow with client_id, a registered callback url and no secret. And it had to run in Jupyter. The user is required to login into the authorization provider's website as part of the redirect (I think. I get mixed up with the terms because for me the Auth provider and the resource were from the same source). To do this I used the python HTTPServer and request handler to intercept the callback url. The Httpserver then hands over the relevant authorization code to my OAuth client when fetching the access token.

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from urllib import parse
import random
import string
import hashlib
import base64
from typing import Any
import webbrowser
from authlib.integrations.requests_client import OAuth2Session

config = {
    'scopes': ['openid', 'profile'],
    'port' : 8888,
    'redirect_url': 'http://localhost:8888/auth/callback',
    'access_token_url': 'https://some_oauth_proivder.com/oauth2/access',
    'auth_code_url': 'https://some_oauth_proivder.com/oauth2/authz/',
    'client_id': 'providedByOauthprovider'}
    

def generate_code() -> tuple[str, str]:
    rand = random.SystemRandom()
    code_verifier = ''.join(rand.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=128))

    code_sha_256 = hashlib.sha256(code_verifier.encode('utf-8')).digest()
    b64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(code_sha_256)
    code_challenge = b64.decode('utf-8').replace('=', '')

    return (code_verifier, code_challenge)
    
    
def login(config: dict[str, Any]) -> str:
    class OAuthHttpServer(HTTPServer):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            HTTPServer.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.authorization_code = ""
        
    class OAuthHttpHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        def do_GET(self):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/html")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write("Redirecting to the My Auth provider login\n".encode("UTF-8"))
        
            parsed = parse.urlparse(self.path)
            client.fetch_token(url=config['access_token_url'],
                    authorization_response=self.path,
                    state=state,
                    code_verifier=code_verifier,
                    grant_type = 'authorization_code')
            
            self.wfile.write("""
                                <html>
                                  <body>
                                    <h2>Authorization request to My Auth provider has been completed.</h1>
                                    <h3>You may close this tab or window now.</h3>                                    
                                  </body>
                                </html>
                                """.encode("UTF-8"))
            self.wfile.write('<script> setTimeout("window.close()", 2500);</script>'.encode("UTF-8")) #Timeout only works if already logged for some reason
        
    with OAuthHttpServer(('', config["port"]), OAuthHttpHandler) as httpd:
        client = OAuth2Session(client_id=config['client_id'],
                               scope=config['scopes'], 
                               redirect_uri=config['redirect_url'],
                               code_challenge_method='S256')
        
        code_verifier, code_challenge = generate_code()
        auth_uri, state = client.create_authorization_url(config['auth_code_url'], code_verifier=code_verifier)

        webbrowser.open_new(auth_uri)
        httpd.handle_request()

    clear_output()
    print("Logged in successfully")
    return client.token['access_token']
```

I borrowed a lot of this from a sample from this guy, but I had to swap out the Oauth client because it didn't work for me. And I had to rearrange the http request handler a little.
https://github.com/CamiloTerevinto/Blog/tree/main/Samples

Answer (score 0):

Well, one answer turns out to be just to use the [requests package](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#web-application-flow), and to copy and paste the redirected URL each time:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
scope = 'all'
redirect_uri='http://localhost:8888/'
oauth = OAuth2Session('YourApplicationApiIdNumber', redirect_uri=redirect_uri, scope=scope)
authorization_url, state = oauth.authorization_url(
        "https://api.mendeley.com/oauth/authorize" )

print( 'Please go to %s to authorize access, and copy the final localhost URL' % authorization_url )
assert(False) # Stop processing until this is done.
```

... into a variable:

```
authorization_response = 'http://localhost:8888/tree?TheStuffWereInterestedIn'
```

... And then take it from there:

```
token = oauth.fetch_token(
        'https://api.mendeley.com/oauth/token',
        authorization_response=authorization_response.replace('http', 'https').replace(',',''),
        client_secret='YourClientSecret')
r = oauth.get('https://api.mendeley.com/documents?sort=last_modified&order=desc&limit=500', timeout=30)
```

You have to configure the Mendeley application interface with the callback URL. This is http://localhost:8888/ , because that's something that Jupyter can display without losing the additional OAuth2 parameters. But Requests OAuth implementation doesn't accept non-https links (nor a trailing comma that Jupyter adds occasionally), so we fudge it as shown.

I guess this approach will work with pretty much any OAuth2 API. Certainly Requests lists [quite a few](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/examples.html).

Comment: My previous solution took a while to execute, as one had to wait for the https request to time out. Instead it turns out that jupyter is happy with http://localhost:8888/?Anything , and keep the anything parameter. Solution amended accordingly.